# Check if post from database date is older then 1,2,3,4 days and take action

Tags: php

I am trying to check if a post stored in a database is older then 1, 2, 3, and, finally, 4 days, respectively.

The table storing all of the posts has a date field. I have a query that retrieves the date and then I try to check if the date is older than 1, 2, 3 and 4 days, respectively and based on the result I want to move posts around the page.

I have the following:

```
foreach($this->getArticleData() as $i)
{
    if(strtotime($i['date']) > strtotime('-1 day'))
    {
        $this->priority = '0.9';
    }
    elseif(strtotime($i['date']) > strtotime('-2 day'))
    {
        $this->priority = '0.8';
    }
    elseif(strtotime($i['date']) > strtotime('-3 day'))
    {
        $this->priority = '0.7';
    }
    else(strtotime($i['date']) > strtotime('-4 day'))
    {
        $this->priority = '0.6';
    }
}
```

I do not think that code is working properly. In some instances the priorities are wrong. I am I using srttotime() function is is there another more reliable way to do this?

Comment: How is your 'date' being formatted?

Comment: Seems like that this should be done in database with a query that retrieves the data.

Comment: You could do that, but you'll need X queries. Lets say, 10 priorities equals to 10 queries. Which is very dirty.

Comment: Hey there my date is structured like this i.e: 2014-07-01 06:57:38. And I dont really wnat to do this at a query level

Answer (score 0):

`Forward slash (/) signifies American M/D/Y formatting, a dash (-) signifies European D-M-Y and a period (.) signifies ISO Y.M.D.`

Your database uses the -'s, you're sure that's right? Anyway, a more sufficient way of your code would be:

```
foreach ( $this->getArticleData() as $i ) {
    for ( $x = 1; $x < 10; $x++ ) {
        if ( strtotime ( $i [ 'date' ] ) > strtotime ( '-'. $x ." day" ) ) {
            $this->priority = '0.'. 10 - $i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flip your `>` around. You're checking if the date is greater/newer than the specified time. You'll also need to flip your `if` statement, because you're checking newest to oldest. A post that is 4 days old is also 1 day old, and will be caught by the first block.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using a priority map and [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) :

```
$list = array(
  array( 'date' => '2014-12-14' ) ,
  array( 'date' => '2014-12-15' ) ,
  array( 'date' => '2014-12-14' ) ,
  array( 'date' => '2014-12-11' ) ,
  array( 'date' => '2014-12-14' ) ,
  array( 'date' => '2014-12-13' ) ,
);

# maps days to priority
$priorities = array(
  1 => 0.9,
  2 => 0.8,
  3 => 0.7,
  4 => 0.6
);

$currentDate = new DateTime();

foreach( $list as $i ) {

  $dateTime = new DateTime( $i['date'] );
  $diff = $currentDate->diff( $dateTime );
  $days = $diff->format( '%d' );

  if( isset( $priorities[ $days ] ) ){
    echo 'Date is: ' . $i['date'] . "| Difference is : " . $days . "| Priority is: " . $priorities[ $days ]. "<br/>";
  }

}
```

Result:

```
Date is: 2014-12-14| Difference is : 1| Priority is: 0.9
Date is: 2014-12-14| Difference is : 1| Priority is: 0.9
Date is: 2014-12-11| Difference is : 4| Priority is: 0.6
Date is: 2014-12-14| Difference is : 1| Priority is: 0.9
Date is: 2014-12-13| Difference is : 2| Priority is: 0.8
```